# Some Gmail Keyboard Shortcuts are not working properly with non-US keyboard

Tags: windows-10, gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, google-schemas

I am using a non-US keyboard (Brazilian ABNT2), and some keyboard shortcuts are not working specifically in **Gmail running on Windows**.

But the same keyboard shortcuts work properly in Gmail running on MacOS.
And also the same keyboard shortcuts work properly in Google Calendar, both in Windows and MacOS.
It seems to be only a Gmail+Windows issue.

I can't use shortcuts with "/" and "" on my Brazilian ABNT2 keyboard, an I believe it's because these keys have a different code/mapping than the same keys in an International-US keyboard:

```
International-US:
[/ ?] = Key 0x0035 (00_35)
[\ |] = Key 0x002B (00_2B)

ABNT2:
[\ |] = Key 0x0056 (00_56)
[/ ?] = Key: 0x0073 (00_73)
```

For some reason, these keys produce the correct effect when **writing** an email. No issues in writing.
But the problem happens when they are used as keyboard shortcuts.

Being more specific with examples, on an ABNT2 keyboard on Gmail+Windows 10:

- pressing "?" key does nothing (and should open the Gmail help);
- pressing "/" key does nothing (and should move the focus to the search box);
- pressing "\" sequence of keys does nothing (and as per my personally configured keyboard shortcuts, should archive the selected email).

Complement 1: These issues are not affecting gmail in my MacOS (everything works properly there). This is happening only in my Windows 10.

Complement 2: this issue is **not affecting Google Calendar** on Windows 10... Pressing "/" correctly moves the focus to the search box, both in MacOS and Windows 10. So it's clearly some problem in Gmail, not in the hardware.

Any ideas on how I could make these exact keyboard shortcuts to work in Gmail on Windows 10?

Is this a bug, and if yes, is there anyone from Google here that can help to address this issue to be corrected?

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

By your description it seems or an hardware issue or some settings in the Gmail account.

Have you checked if the setting for the shortcuts is actually on?

1. On a computer, go to Gmail.
2. In the top right, click Settings  and then ‘See all settings.’
3. Click Settings.
4. Scroll down to the "Keyboard shortcuts" section.
5. Select Keyboard shortcuts on.
6. At the bottom of the page, click Save Changes.

Keyboard shortcuts for Gmail: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594

If is not this then I suggest you to do some testing with your hardware.

I tell you this because by experience this doesn't seems like a bug at all for the simple reason that in a Mac works but in a windows it doesn't. Also it is very unlikely that there may be some discrepancy between the gmail web UI and a OS, but rather between the gmail UI and the browser firstly.

Actually by putting in order what you should check first:

1. Hardware, check by changing the keyboard language in the windows system ---> Switch between languages using the Language bar: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-languages-using-the-language-bar-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258

.2 If doesn't help try on a different Windows computer and with a different Keyboard.

.3 If still not working then use a different Browser (is the browser that is interacting with the webpage, in this case gmail.google.com and not the device OS directly with Gmail).

If then you see then is not solving you may report this by going in the top right corner in gmail.google.com, press the question mark (?) logo and leave a feedback as it would be the best way to directly comunicate with a Googler.